# How to store data from txt file in XML file using c#?

Tags: c#, xml

i stored data from user in text file using delimiters and this is my code doing this

```
Student std = new Student();
dataGridView1.Rows.Clear(); //to clear the dataGridView Before showing the data
dataGridView1.Refresh();
List<Student> students = new List<Student>();
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(txt_path.Text))
{
    int x = 0;
    while (sr.Peek() >= 0)
    {
        string str;
        string[] strArray;
        str = sr.ReadLine();

        strArray = str.Split('@', '#');
        Student s = new Student();
        s.ID = int.Parse(strArray[0]);
        s.Name = strArray[1];
        s.Address = strArray[2];
        s.Phone = strArray[3];

        DataGridViewRow row = new DataGridViewRow();
        row.CreateCells(dataGridView1);  // this line was missing
        row.Cells[x].Value = s.ID;
        row.Cells[++x].Value = s.Name;
        row.Cells[++x].Value = s.Address;
        row.Cells[++x].Value = s.Phone;

        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
        students.Add(s);
        x = 0;
    }
}
```

here's the problem, after i store data in text file, then i want to keep it in XML file like "in the picture".

[image]

i tried but i failed like in this picture

[image]

this is the code for what i make in the seconde picture

```
            try
        {
            List<Student> students = new List<Student>();
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(txt_path.Text))
            {

                string xmlc = string.Empty;
                while (sr.Peek() >= 0)
                {
                    string str;
                    string[] strArray;

                    str = sr.ReadLine();

                    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(str) && !str.StartsWith("#"))
                    {
                        xmlc += str;
                        strArray = xmlc.Split('@', '#');
                        saveXml.saveData(xmlc, "data.xml");
                        saveXml.saveData(strArray, "data.xml");
                    }

                    Student s = new Student();
                    s.ID = int.Parse(strArray[0]);
                    s.Name = strArray[1];
                    s.Address = strArray[2];
                    s.Phone = strArray[3];




                    students.Add(s);


                }
            }
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
```

[text file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z1xvr.png)

Comment: Can you show us the code which is used for creating/writing to `Xml`?

Comment: @HariPrasad i edited my question.

Comment: @FelicePollano but this store data in dataGridview and text file

Comment: Show us your text file.

Comment: So the question is how to generate an Xml file for List of students?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov i edited my question and insert the text file.

Comment: @HariPrasad yes Exactly!

Answer (score 0):

It is bit unclear, looking at your code I assume you want to read a text file and generate an `Xml` file.

You could do something like this.

```
var students = File.ReadLines(txt_path.Text)
    .Select(line=>line.Split('@', '#')
    .Select(x=> new Student()
                {
                    ID = int.Parse(x[0]),
                    Name = x[1],
                    Address = x[2],
                    Phone = x[3]
                }) 
    .ToList();
```

Once you get list of Students you could use `Linq` to `Xml` and create an xml file.

```
XElement element = 
    new XElement("Students",
        (from student in students 
             select new XElement("Student",
                 new XElement("ID", student.ID),
                 new XElement("Name",student.Name),
                 new XElement("Address", student.Address),
                 new XElement("Phone",student.Phone)
             )
         )
     ); 

 element.Save(outputfile);
```

Last but not least you could use `List<Student>` as binding source to  `DataGridView`.

```
dataGridView1.DataSource new BindingSource(new BindingList<Student>(students);
```

Check this [`demo`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/0om417) you'll get an idea how this works.